ArduinoFFT library argument list compilation error in Arduino
I am creating a sound visualizer using an arduino nano,electret condenser microphone and 8X32 matrix and i keep getting the same error.
here is the code:
#include <ArduinoFFT.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoMatrix.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

#define PIN_MATRIX 2 // Arduino Nano Pin D2 to DIN of matrix
#define PIN_MIC 0   // Arduino Nano Analog Pin A0 to microphone Vout
#define MATRIX_WIDTH 32
#define MATRIX_HEIGHT 8
#define MIC_SAMPLE_SIZE 48 // Change according to your mic module's specifications

ArduinoFFT fft;

Adafruit_NeoMatrix matrix = Adafruit_NeoMatrix(MATRIX_WIDTH, MATRIX_HEIGHT, PIN_MATRIX,
  NEO_MATRIX_TOP     + NEO_MATRIX_LEFT +
  NEO_MATRIX_COLUMNS + NEO_MATRIX_ZIGZAG,
  NEO_GRB            + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  matrix.begin();
  matrix.setTextWrap(false);
  matrix.setBrightness(50); // Adjust brightness as needed
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color(255, 255, 255)); // Text color
  fft.begin(MIC_SAMPLE_SIZE); // Initialize the FFT object
}

void loop() {
  fft.Execute(); // Run FFT

  int max_index = 0;
  int max_value = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < MIC_SAMPLE_SIZE / 2; i++) {
    int value = fft.Output[i]; // Read FFT result
    if (value > max_value) {
      max_value = value;
      max_index = i;
    }
  }

  // Map max_index to matrix columns
  int column = map(max_index, 0, MIC_SAMPLE_SIZE / 2, 0, MATRIX_WIDTH);

  // Clear matrix
  matrix.fillScreen(0);

  // Draw bar on matrix
  for (int y = 0; y < MATRIX_HEIGHT; y++) {
    matrix.drawPixel(column, y, matrix.Color(255, 255, 255)); // White color
  }

  matrix.show();
}


Here is the error:
/Users/vyomesh/Documents/Arduino/sketch_apr22a/sketch_apr22a.ino:12:1: error: invalid use of template-name 'ArduinoFFT' without an argument list
 ArduinoFFT fft;
 ^~~~~~~~~~
/Users/vyomesh/Documents/Arduino/sketch_apr22a/sketch_apr22a.ino:12:1: note: class template argument deduction is only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
In file included from /Users/vyomesh/Documents/Arduino/sketch_apr22a/sketch_apr22a.ino:1:0:
/Users/vyomesh/Documents/Arduino/libraries/arduinoFFT/src/ArduinoFFT.h:58:29: note: 'template<class T> class ArduinoFFT' declared here
 template <typename T> class ArduinoFFT {
                             ^~~~~~~~~~
/Users/vyomesh/Documents/Arduino/sketch_apr22a/sketch_apr22a.ino: In function 'void setup()':
/Users/vyomesh/Documents/Arduino/sketch_apr22a/sketch_apr22a.ino:25:3: error: 'fft' was not declared in this scope
   fft.begin(MIC_SAMPLE_SIZE); // Initialize the FFT object
   ^~~
/Users/vyomesh/Documents/Arduino/sketch_apr22a/sketch_apr22a.ino:25:3: note: suggested alternative: 'ffs'
   fft.begin(MIC_SAMPLE_SIZE); // Initialize the FFT object
   ^~~
   ffs
/Users/vyomesh/Documents/Arduino/sketch_apr22a/sketch_apr22a.ino: In function 'void loop()':
/Users/vyomesh/Documents/Arduino/sketch_apr22a/sketch_apr22a.ino:29:3: error: 'fft' was not declared in this scope
   fft.Execute(); // Run FFT
   ^~~
/Users/vyomesh/Documents/Arduino/sketch_apr22a/sketch_apr22a.ino:29:3: note: suggested alternative: 'ffs'
   fft.Execute(); // Run FFT
   ^~~
   ffs

exit status 1

Compilation error: invalid use of template-name 'ArduinoFFT' without an argument list

Matrix Wiring:
GND-GND
5V-5V
DIN-D2
Electret condenser michrophone:
Positive- A0 and connected to 5V through resistor
Negative- GND
Other info: Macos sonoma
library name- ArduinoFFT.h

Restarted IDE
Reinstalled the library
tried different versions
sought help from ChatGPT as a last resort (still failed)


This is a build-related issue. It has nothing to do with your electronic design ..
According to the GitHub page of the project, you are expected to provide some parameters to the constructor:
/*
These are the input and output vectors
Input vectors receive computed results from FFT
*/
double vReal[samples];
double vImag[samples];

ArduinoFFT<double> FFT = ArduinoFFT<double>(vReal, vImag, samples, samplingFrequency);

The above code is taken from the example file FFT_01.ino hosted on the project's GitHub page.
